# Modern Warfare 2: Pistol run distance

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Does holding a pistol make you run further (or faster) than your primary weapon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't able to find an 'official answer' but there were a number of sources that said only the primary affects your speed.

From [this site](http://denkirson.xanga.com/715966769/modern-warfare-2/)

> On movement speed (player speed is
>   determined by the weapon in his
>   primary slot): SMGs and Sniper Rifles
>   have a Speed of 100% Assault Rifles
>   have a Speed of 95% Machineguns have a
>   Speed of 87.5% Riot Shield has a Speed
>   of 80% A player can pick up another
>   weapon and keep the movement speed of
>   the weapon he spawned with.

From [game FAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/951944-call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2/54601841)

> Only primaries affect running speed so
>   pistols don't count.  Also, it goes
>   like this: SMG's/Snipers > AR's >
>   LMG's > Riot shield

On a semi related note: Lightweight will multiply the player's movement speed by 1.1x ( 8% to 10% increase depending on the weapon).

Comment: Thats interesting, so spawning with an SMG or Sniper its possible to pick up a Riot Shield or LMG and run full speed?

Comment: Going by the information I found that would be possible.

Comment: This is really useful information. Great data visual presentation of this complex information.

Comment: @Aardvark No. The speed you move at is the slowest speed among the weapons you are carrying. If you pick up a riot shield, you move at riot shield speed, regardless of what other weapon you have or what you spawned with. Also, I could've sworn the lightweight speed was x 1.15, but maybe not.